# Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to write in the cache directory

Tags: symfony

When I try do deploy my website on the server I have this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to write in the cache directory (/home/e120223/public_html/ReclyZone/app/cache/prod) ' in /home/e120223/public_html/ReclyZone/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:597 Stack trace: #0 /home/e120223/public_html/ReclyZone/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(510): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() #1 /home/e120223/public_html/ReclyZone/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(133): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() #2 /home/e120223/public_html/ReclyZone/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(182): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() #3 /home/e120223/public_html/ReclyZone/web/app.php(16): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #4 {main} thrown in /home/e120223/public_html/ReclyZone/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php on line 597

I have already clear cache but nothing works, do you have an idea ?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: Make sure the permissions are fine in the cache directory, later use `cache:clear --no-warmup & cache-warmup` to avoid random errors.

Comment: @Cerad and for windows ?

Comment: Your production server is running windows?  Yikes.  All I can suggest is to copy/paste "Unable to write in the cache directory windows" into a search bar and see what comes up.

Comment: @Cerad it is not my serveur it is my school serveur so I don't give you that :/

Comment: Once you figure it out then you should submit a pull request to the documentation site.  Be a nice line item on your resume.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod -R 777`on the cache directory to give permission to read AND write

Comment: Be careful.  This can result in some serious security issues on production servers.  A more nuanced approach might be better.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: @Yceruto chmod is not valide in window ?

Comment: @PierreColart https://superuser.com/questions/106181/equivalent-of-chmod-to-change-file-permissions-in-windows

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you don't have permission to write in that cache directory.
I would change the default cache directory to a writable folder.

See the official documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-cache-dir